# How to create average value by group and assign loop ID to generate a polygon in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this:

```py
mydict = {'year' : [2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011],
          'region' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
          'group' : ['lower', 'upper', 'lower', 'upper', 'lower', 'upper', 'lower', 'upper'],
          'var' : [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]}
pd.DataFrame(mydict)
```

It should be straightforward, the only note is for each year in each region, the value of `var` in `lower` group is always smaller than in `upper`.
I need to do the following:

- Generate a new column `average`, which, for each year, is equal to the average of `var`
- Generate a new column `loop`, which, for each region and year, assign a pair of number to lower and upper group from 2 ends of the length of the region. That sounds awkward for a description, but the resulting data looks like this:

```py
newdict = {'year' : [2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011],
          'region' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
          'group' : ['lower', 'upper', 'lower', 'upper', 'lower', 'upper', 'lower', 'upper'],
          'var' : [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80],
          'average' : [15,15,35,35,55,55,75,75],
          'loop' : [0,3,1,2,0,3,1,2]}
pd.DataFrame(newdict)
```

So for the `loop` column, you see as group 1 has 4 elements, then the numbers are assigned to the rows in a way that tries to make a loop, which will be used to define a polygon. In this case, 0 is assigned to 2010-lower, 1 to 2011 lower, 2 to 2011 upper, and 3 to 2010 upper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average per group is straightforward.

If I understand correctly, you could sort the values with a custom order (lower then upper, lower increasing, upper decreasing) and [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['average'] = df.groupby(['year', 'region'])['var'].transform('mean')

df['loop'] = (df.assign(var=df['var'].mask(df['group'].eq('upper'), -df['var']))
                 .sort_values(by=['group', 'var'])
                 .groupby('region').cumcount()
              )
```

Output:

```
   year  region  group  var  loop2  average  loop
0  2010       1  lower   10      0     15.0     0
1  2010       1  upper   20      3     15.0     3
2  2011       1  lower   30      1     35.0     1
3  2011       1  upper   40      2     35.0     2
4  2010       2  lower   50      0     55.0     0
5  2010       2  upper   60      3     55.0     3
6  2011       2  lower   70      1     75.0     1
7  2011       2  upper   80      2     75.0     2
```